# Having trouble copying a String in an array to a String variable

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm doing a relatively simple file read, and I've been experiencing anomalies in my validation between an input value and a data value read from a flat file and stored in an array. I've traced the error to the `firstName` field. I'm defining this field as equal to `array[0]`. `While array[0]` displays perfectly in my output, `fieldName` does not...it's either blank or null.

Here's my code, with an output sample.

I'm not sure if `Stringbuilder` is most appropriately used here? or one of the deep String methods? None of what I've tried seems to work. What am I missing...I know it's something obvious that I just can't see.

```
public class DisplaySelectedNumbers
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String FN = "            ";
        final String LN = "            ";
        final String PHONE = "0000000000";
        String delimiter = ",";
        String s = FN + delimiter + LN + delimiter + PHONE + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        final int RECSIZE = s.length();
        String[] array = new String[3];
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        Path file = Paths.get("PhoneList.txt");
        String fName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter first name to search");
        try
        {
            InputStream iStream=new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file));
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                array = s.split(delimiter);
                String dispString = array[0]+" "+array[1]+" "+array[2]+"\n";
                System.out.println("array[0]="+array[0]);
                System.out.println("array[1]="+array[1]);
                System.out.println("array[2]="+array[2]);
                String firstName = array[0];
                System.out.println("firstName=");
                    s=reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Message: " + e);
        }
    }
}


array[0]=D
array[1]=JJ
array[2]=0123450000
firstName=
array[0]=B
array[1]=EE
array[2]=1111111111
firstName=
array[0]=D
array[1]=GG
array[2]=0033333333
firstName=
```

Comment: Lol, you seriously are not able to figure it out? :P This is what happens when you over think stuff :-)

Comment: indeed, indeed. It's been a long day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to actually print the `firstName` variable:

```
System.out.println("firstName=");
```

You need instead:

```
System.out.println("firstName=" + firstName);
```

Comment: Hey, guess what! It works! OMG. Can I downvote myself for being blind? Thansk for the second set of eyes.

Comment: Don't worry and no need to downvote. This can happen to anyone!

Answer (score 1):

Not really a complete answer for your question, but yes, using StringBuilder in your code would be better if you need to improve String concatenation speed, specially in a loop.

[StringBuilder vs String concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)